# Add a folder to bin (debug/release) in post-build

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder in my project. And inside that folder are files that my program is going to read from at run-time (i.e. most important one of them). So if the folder name is "xyxyxy" and if I am looking for the file "zzz.xml" in that folder I can access that file by

```
if (File.Exists(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/xyxyxy/zzz.xml"))
    MessageBox.Show("File found!");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not found!");
```

How can add this entire folder to the bin folder (both in debug and release)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Visual Studio, for the file you want to be copied to folders under bin, mark the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the file as `Copy always`. That should output the file, along with the folder structure to wherever the binaries are emitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a **post-build step** for that in the project that contains the executable you are running. You can use the **macro's** to determine the exact directory that your dll's/exe are copied to to create your directory and files.

Comment: Now that I see that your files already belong to (one of) your project(s), the solution provided by Vikas is probably better/easier. Post-build steps are better suited for 'special' tasks that you want to have done/copied after a build has completed.